# PyQt6 Rounded corners on MainWindow when using FramelessWindowHint

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, qt6, pyqt6

I am working on a tool and am using PyQt6 as the GUI. I am using `setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowType.FramelessWindowHint)` to remove the windows toolbar, however I wish to also make the MainWidnow have rounded corners. I have tried editing the stylesheet by adding

```
QMainWindow{
    border: 5px solid #455364;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

this adds the border with the radius, however it leaves it looking like this:
https://shorturl.at/tJ678
with the 90 degree corner still left behind. I am looking for a way to add the rounded corners without this.

Comment: If you need to show an image then please add it 'in-place' in the question: not via a (broken?) link.

Comment: It's the "title bar", a toolbar is a completely different thing. Try adding `self.setAttribute(Qt.WidgetAttribute.WA_TranslucentBackground)`